# MediaType with additional info

Tags: android, multipart, okhttp

When creating an Multipart/related request. We need add an additional  `type=MIME_TYPE` to the `Content-Type` string

The Content-Type should look like this

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=boundary_1324; type="application/json";
```

When Looking at the MultipartBody constructor

```
MultipartBody(ByteString boundary, MediaType type, List<Part> parts) {
    this.boundary = boundary;
    this.originalType = type;
    this.contentType = MediaType.parse(type + "; boundary=" + boundary.utf8());
    this.parts = Util.immutableList(parts);
  }
```

We are allowed to add the boundary token.

But when calling `MediaType.parse` like this

```
final MediaType parse = MediaType.parse("multipart/related; type=application/json");
```

The object parse is `null`.

Anyone got an idea on how to add `type=application/json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote the value, and don't include the trailing ;

```
MediaType mt = MediaType.parse("multipart/related; type=\"application/json\"");
```

This matches the spec, which expects either a simple token or a quoted string. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-5.1

n.b. MediaType won't extract type for you, but shouldn't fail.